# <bound method Player.roll_dice <player.Player object at 0x0000000003569550>

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am confused once again, I'm getting an error `<bound method Player.roll_dice <player.Player object at 0x0000000003569550>` for a StringVar() called roll taken from a method in the player.py file

gui.py

```
try:
    from tkinter import *
    from player import *
    from monster import *
    from random import *
except ImportError as err:
    print('Import Error',err)

class SimpleGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title('Final Project')
        self.window.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW',self.exit)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.window,
                             width = 245,
                             height = 550,
                             bg = 'white')
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.player = Player()

        self.menu = Menu()

        self.monster = monster

        self.canvas.focus_set()
        self.canvas.bind('w', self.w_key)
        self.canvas.bind('a', self.a_key)
        self.canvas.bind('s', self.s_key)
        self.canvas.bind('d', self.d_key)

        frame1 = Frame(self.window)
        frame1.pack()

        self.player_hp = StringVar()
        self.player_hp.set(int(self.player.hp))

        self.monster_hp = StringVar()
        self.monster_hp.set(int(self.monster.e_hp))

        Label(frame1, text = "Player HP:").grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        ply_hp = Label(frame1, textvariable = self.player_hp).grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        Label(frame1, text = "Monster HP:").grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        monster_hp = Label(frame1, textvariable = self.monster_hp).grid(row = 2, column = 2)



        self.bt_attack = Button(frame1,
                                text = 'Attack',
                                command = print('x')).grid(row = 3, column = 0)

        self.bt_defend = Button(frame1,
                                text = 'Defend',
                                command = print('x')).grid(row = 3, column = 2)


        self.dcroll = StringVar()
        self.dcroll.set(self.player.roll_dice)


        self.bt_roll = Button(frame1,
                              text = 'Roll Dice',
                              command = self.player.roll_dice).grid(row = 3, column = 1)


        Label(frame1, text = 'YOU ROLLED:').grid(row = 4, column = 1)
        roll = Label(frame1, textvariable = self.dcroll).grid(row = 4, column = 2)



        self.running = True
        self.menu = Menu()

        self.bt1 = Button(self.window,
                         text = 'Start / Reset',
                         command = self.menu)
        self.bt1.pack()




        self.mainloop()
        self.window.mainloop()

    def mainloop(self):
        while self.running:
            self.canvas.delete(ALL)
            #boss square
            boss_start = self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,0,150,100, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            #player start square
            ply_start = self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,500,150,550, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            #row 9
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,50,50,100, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(50,50,100,100, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,50,150,100, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(150,50,200,100, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(200,50,250,100, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            #row 8
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,100,50,150, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(50,100,100,150, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,100,150,150, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(150,100,200,150, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(200,100,250,150, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            #row 7
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,150,50,200, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(50,150,100,200, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,150,150,200, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(150,150,200,200, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(200,150,250,200, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            #row 6
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,200,50,250, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(50,200,100,250, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,200,150,250, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(150,200,200,250, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(200,200,250,250, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            #row 5
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,250,50,300, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(50,250,100,300, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,250,150,300, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(150,250,200,300, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(200,250,250,300, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            #row 4
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,300,50,350, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(50,300,100,350, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,300,150,350, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(150,300,200,350, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(200,300,250,350, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            #row 3
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,350,50,400, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(50,350,100,400, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,350,150,400, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(150,350,200,400, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(200,350,250,400, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            #row 2
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,400,50,450, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(50,400,100,450, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,400,150,450, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(150,400,200,450, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(200,400,250,450, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            #row 1
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,450,50,500, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(50,450,100,500, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,450,150,500, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(150,450,200,500, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(200,450,250,500, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.player.draw(self.canvas)


            self.player_hp.set(int(self.player.hp))

            self.monster_hp.set(int(self.monster.e_hp))

            self.canvas.after(30)
            self.canvas.update()




#------Functions------#



    def button1(self):
        print('working')

    def a_key(self, event):
        self.player.x -= self.player.speed
        if self.player.x < 0:
            self.player.x = 0
        if self.player.y == 0:
            if self.player.x <= 100:
                self.player.x = 100
        if self.player.y == 500:
            if self.player.x <= 100:
                self.player.x = 100

    def w_key(self, event):
        self.player.y -= self.player.speed
        if self.player.y < 0:
            self.player.y = 0
        if self.player.x < 100:
            if self.player.y == 0:
                self.player.y = 50
        if self.player.x > 100:
            if self.player.y == 0:
                self.player.y = 50

    def s_key(self, event):
        self.player.y += self.player.speed
        if self.player.y > 500:
            self.player.y = 500
        if self.player.x < 100:
            if self.player.y == 500:
                self.player.y = 450
        if self.player.x > 100:
            if self.player.y == 500:
                self.player.y = 450

    def d_key(self, event):
        self.player.x += self.player.speed
        if self.player.x > 200:
            self.player.x = 200
        if self.player.y == 0:
            if self.player.x >= 150:
                self.player.x = 100
        if self.player.y == 500:
            if self.player.x >= 150:
                self.player.x = 100


    def battle(self, monster):
        while True:
            self.player.attack(monster)
            monster.attack(self.player)
            self.canvas.after(200)
            if self.player.hp <= 0 or monster.e_hp <= 0:
                break

    def exit(self):
        self.running = False
        self.window.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SimpleGUI()
```

player.py

```
try:
    from random import *
    from monster import *

except ImportError as err:
    print('Import Error, ', err)


class Player:
    def __init__(self, hp = 100, defense = 10, strength = 10):
        self.hp = hp
        self.defense = defense
        self.strength = strength
        self.x = 100
        self.y = 500
        self.speed = 50
        self.d1 = randint(1,6)
        self.d2 = randint(1,6)
        self.roll = (self.d1 + self.d2)

    def draw(self, canvas): 
        canvas.create_oval(self.x,self.y,self.x+50,self.y+50, fill='red')

    def roll_dice(self):
        self.roll = (self.d1 + self.d2)

        self.dcroll = StringVar()
        self.dcroll.set(int(self.roll))

    def attack(self, other):
        attack = self.roll
        for x in [7,11,12]:
            if attack == x:
                hit = monster.e_hp - self.strength
                monster.e_hp = hit
                break
        for x in [2,3,4]:
            if attack == x:
                player_hit = monster.e_strength - self.hp
                self.hp = player_hit

        other.e_hp -= self.strength

if __name__ == '__main__':
    player = Player()
```

As you can see the error "" sits where it says YOU ROLLED: . How can I fix this? Also is there an easy way to call a function each time the player moves? Or would it be best to write if the x and y values change call on function x?

Comment: What error?  Each time, you just show quotes with nothing between them.

Comment: Please include the entire error message, including whatever stack trace you get, in your question.

Comment: <bound method Player.roll_dice <player.Player object at 0x0000000003569550>

Comment: that is the error I get IN the program, its in the gui.py file.

Comment: Instead of printing d1 + d2 it prints off <bound method Player.roll_dice <player.Player object at 0x0000000003569550>

Comment: Also whenever I press the button Roll Dice in the GUI it gives me this error:

"Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\The Surgeon\Desktop\Final Project\player.py", line 32, in roll_dice
    self.dcroll = StringVar()
NameError: name 'StringVar' is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

I did see the following bug

```
    roll = Label(frame1, textvariable = self.dcroll).grid(row = 4, column = 2)
```

binds `roll` to the result of the grid call, `None`, rather than to the Label widget.  This must cause a problem if you ever use `roll`.  This is a common beginner mistake.  The code should be

```
    roll = Label(frame1, textvariable = self.dcroll)
    roll.grid(row = 4, column = 2)
```

The same is true for ply_hp and monster_hp.